# How Do You Test Multi-Currency Logic?

Tags: apex, unit-test, test-setup

You cannot setup any currency during apex tests, and therefore any logic that works on the currency of records is untestable. Am I correct?

- The CurrencyType does not support DML (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dml_non_dml_objects.htm?search_text=support%20DML).
- Currencies work for scratch orgs, you can import them via `force:data:tree:import`. I tried, to create currencies in tests, but the code does not compile.
- Neither the Test-namespace nor the static test class supports methods to work with currencies.

So: How do you test code with multi-currency?

Comment: Please check if this test class [code](https://github.com/SonarSource/apex-test-sources/blob/master/projects/Cumulus/src/classes/ALLO_Multicurrency_TEST.cls) could help getting some insight on your particular requirement.

Comment: No, it does not.